# The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later( Olivero subtheme)

Tags: theming

Tried to make an Olivero subtheme. Followed drupal tutorials and after several unsuccessfull attempts ended in error "**The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later**" on both backend and frontend now I don't get the error anymore on the backend but I still can't access the frontend.

Error in drupal log looks like this

```
Drupal\Core\Asset\Exception\InvalidLibraryFileException: Invalid library definition in themes/mysubtheme/mysubtheme.libraries.yml: A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 1 (near "global-styling: version: 1.x "). in Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->parseLibraryInfo() (line 348 of /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryParser.php).
```

mysubtheme.info.yml looks like this

```
type: theme
base theme: olivero
description: My custom theme based on the core Olivero theme. It's meant for customization.
package: Custom
libraries:
  - mysubtheme/css
  - mysubtheme/js

regions:
  header: Header
  primary_menu: 'Primary menu'
  secondary_menu: 'Secondary menu'
  hero: 'Hero (full width)'
  highlighted: Highlighted
  breadcrumb: Breadcrumb
  social: Social Bar
  content_above: Content Above
  content: Content
  sidebar: 'Sidebar'
  content_below: 'Content Below (Flex Layout)'
  footer_top: 'Footer Top (Flex Layout)'
  footer_bottom: 'Footer Bottom'

core: '8.x'
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
```

and mysubtheme.libraries.yml like this

```
 version: VERSION
 css:
   theme:
     css/custom.css: {}

global-scripts:
 version: VERSION
 dependencies:
   - core/jquery
   - core/drupal
   - core/drupalSettings
 js:
     js/custom.js: {}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In the info file the JS must be: `- mysubtheme/global-scripts` and the CSS is actually missing a name in the *.libraries.yml.

Comment: As ^ said, but I think the css should probably be part of the `global-scripts` library instead of being another separate library.

Comment: The Olivero theme doesn't support subthemes https://www.drupal.org/blog/drupal-9-1-0 `Subtheming Olivero is currently not supported, but formal support may be included in the future.` that's potentially part of the issue

Comment: leymannx, I'll fix it. Leigh, didn't know. It's a pitty that Olivero doesn't support subtheming for now. I'll have to look for something elese but nothing comes close to that looks. :(

Answer (score 0):

As @Leigh wrote in a comment one of the cause of my problem is that, sadly, OLivero doesn't support yet subtheming.